# How to use Odds ratio feature selection with Naive bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification

I want to classify documents (composed of words) into 3 classes (Positive, Negative, Unknown/Neutral). A subset of the document words become the features.

Until now, I have programmed a Naive Bayes Classifier using as a feature selector Information gain and chi-square statistics. Now, I would like to see what happens if I use Odds ratio as a feature selector.

My problem is that I don't know hot to implement Odds-ratio. Should I:

1) Calculate Odds Ratio for every word w, every class:
   E.g. for w:

```
   Prob of word as positive Pw,p = #positive docs with w/#docs
   Prob of word as negative Pw,n = #negative docs with w/#docs
   Prob of word as unknown Pw,u = #unknown docs with w/#docs

   OR(Wi,P) = log( Pw,p*(1-Pw,p) / (Pw,n + Pw,u)*(1-(Pw,n + Pw,u)) ) 
   OR(Wi,N) ...
   OR(Wi,U) ...
```

2) How should I decide if I choose or not the word as a feature ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd ratio is not good measure for feature selection, because it is only shows what happen when feature present, and nothing when it is not. So it will not work for rare features and almost all features are rare so it not work for almost all features. Example feature with 100% confidence that class is positive which present in 0.0001 is useless for classification. Therefore if you still want to use odd ratio add threshold on frequency of feature, like feature present in 5% of cases. But I would recommend better approach - use Chi or info gain metrics which automatically solve those problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I have a wrong idea about Odds Ratio. OR seems to be useful for extracting features according to their relevance for a certain class (for example, a word with a high OR score in Positive class is likely to be positive word). Since I am using words to categorize sentiment of text documents, some words repeat in documents and not all features are rare in my case... right ?

Comment: My point that you will not get good representative among other only by odds ratio. Simple example all words which are mentioned only once will have 1 odd ratio and they are useless.  If you sort words which mentioned in text at least 15 times it will give your meaningful result.

Comment: Oh, I see, using words appearing over a certain frequency can together with OR could led to good results...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since it took me a while to independently wrap my head around all this, let me explain my findings here for the benefit of humanity.

Using the (log) odds ratio is a standard technique for filtering features prior to text classification.  It is a 'one-sided metric' [Zheng et al., 2004] in the sense that it only discovers features which are positively correlated with a particular class.  As a log-odds-ratio for the probability of seeing a feature 't' given the class 'c', it is defined as:

```
LOR(t,c) = log [Pr(t|c) / (1 - Pr(t|c))] : [Pr(t|!c) / (1 - Pr(t|!c))]
= log [Pr(t|c) (1 - Pr(t|!c))] / [Pr(t|!c) (1 - Pr(t|c))]
```

Here I use '!c' to mean a document where the class is *not* c.

But how do you actually calculate Pr(t|c) and Pr(t|!c)?

One subtlety to note is that feature selection probabilities, in general, are usually defined over a *document event model* [McCallum & Nigam 1998, Manning et al. 2008], i.e., Pr(t|c) is the probability of seeing term t *one or more times* in the document given the class of the document is c (in other words, the presence of t given the class c).  The maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of this probability would be the proportion of documents of class c that contain t at least once.  [Technically, this is known as a Multivariate Bernoulli event model, and is distinct from a Multinomial event model over words, which would calculate Pr(t|c) using integer word counts - see the McCallum paper or the Manning IR textbook for more details, specifically on how this applies to a Naive Bayes text classifier.]

One key to using LOR effectively is to *smooth* these conditional probability estimates, since, as @yura noted, rare events are problematic here (e.g., the MLE of Pr(t|!c) could be zero, leading to an infinite LOR).  But how do we smooth?

In the literature, Forman reports smoothing the LOR by "adding one to any zero count in the denominator" (Forman, 2003), while Zheng et al (2004) use "ELE [Expected Likelihood Estimation] smoothing" which usually amounts to adding 0.5 to each count.

To smooth in a way that is consistent with probability theory, I follow standard practices in text classification with a Multivariate Bernoulli event model.  Essentially, we assume that we have seen each presence count AND each absence count B extra times.  So our estimate for Pr(t|c) can be written in terms of #(t,c): the number of times we've seen t and c, and #(t,!c): the number of times we've seen t without c, as follows:

```
Pr(t|c) = [#(t,c) + B] / [#(t,c) + #(t,!c) + 2B]
 = [#(t,c) + B] / [#(c) + 2B]
```

If `B = 0`, we have the MLE.  If `B = 0.5`, we have ELE.  If `B = 1`, we have the Laplacian prior.  Note this looks different than smoothing for the Multinomial event model, where the Laplacian prior leads you to add |V| in the denominator [McCallum & Nigam, 1998]

You can choose `0.5` or `1` as your smoothing value, depending on which prior work most inspires you, and plug this into the equation for `LOR(t,c)` above, and score all the features.

Typically, you then decide on how many features you want to use, say N, and then choose the N highest-ranked features based on the score.

In a multi-class setting, people have often used 1 vs All classifiers and thus did feature selection independently for each classifier and thus each positive class with the 1-sided metrics (Forman, 2003).  However, if you want to find a unique reduced set of features that works in a multiclass setting, there are some advanced approaches in the literature (e.g. Chapelle & Keerthi, 2008).

References:

> Zheng, Wu, Srihari, 2004
>
> McCallum & Nigam 1998
>
> Manning, Raghavan & Schütze, 2008
>
> Forman, 2003
>
> Chapelle & Keerthi, 2008